# How do you change plotBackGroundColor dynamically if value exceeds a maxium value in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Seems like this should be pretty simple in such an amazing tool as HighCharts, but I can't find anything like it for an example.  I built a page for my Raspberry Pi to chart the temperatures of a refrigerator.  I would like the chart to have a fill color of red below any point that exceeds 40 degree line.  I circled the areas in red in the picture below that I would like to have a red fill color below the sections of line graph.
[image: Picture of My Graph]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using negative color and threshold .However its tricky as it changes color below a certain level and in your case you want to change color of graph **above** certain values (not below).

See  [Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/p2o0a480/)

you can use

```
  threshold : 45,//whatever you want to make upper level
  color: '#FF0000', //Actually color for high values
  negativeColor: '#7cb5ec' //color for normal values.
```

Alternatively you can also use plotbands  to highlight particular section, but that won't specify your date-range for which temperature is above normal.